# How to get a complete file from mail attachment in java to send it through another APIs input?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, asana

I am creating an application where I need to get file attached in mail and then send that complete file as input of another API of portal called 'asana'. I don't want to save/ download the file locally.

I referred this [site](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/download-attachments-in-e-mail-messages-using-javamail) to get the attached file through mail.
But, I need to send the file to 'asana' API without downloading it.
Here is the code of asana API to send file through API.

```
String url = "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/"+asanaActivitiesDto.getTaskId()+"/attachments";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + asanaActivitiesDto.getBearerToken());

            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.addTextBody("task", jsonInput.get("taskId").toString(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            // now here I actually want file from attachment of the mail
           // currently taking file from local for testing
            File f = new File(asanaActivitiesDto.getFile());
            builder.addBinaryBody(
                "file",
                //Here, as a second input, I need to set file from the 
                //attachment of the mail
                new FileInputStream(f),
                ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
                f.getName()
            );
            HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
            post.setEntity(multipart);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(result.toString());
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            jsonOutput = (JSONObject) parser.parse(result.toString());
```

at the place of **new FileInputStream(f)**, I need to send file attached to that mail. What are the possible ways to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the data in the email attachment as an InputStream.  Try something like:

```
        mbp = // the MimeBodyPart containing the attachment
        builder.addBinaryBody(
            "file",
            mbp.getInputStream(),
            ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
            mbp.getFileName()
        );
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the same but it gives me error like:
java.io.FileNotFoundException:<fileName> (No such file or directory)
Please check full stack trace here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jDnRlViWBujH9q5i1qTo5FyEoJ2XBgFtSDBQJSr_WSQ

Any suggestions on the same please?

Comment: Are you writing an AWS Lamba function that’s triggered by an email message?  Who creates the email message?  Is it being created by some other part of your application?